# What to do before asking a minecraft-commands question?

Tags: discussion, faq, minecraft

Want to ask a question in [minecraft-commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-commands)? Don't know how to summon an entity or give a player an item? Read this guide first to make sure it isn’t already covered here, or in one of the linked wikis or questions.

Comment: I wasn't really sure where to put this, so I put it in Meta. If this could be linked on the intro page, or maybe as a resource in the help section that would probably help a lot of people in finding it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first thing you should do before asking a question is read [this guide to Minecraft Commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/354614), to make sure that you know the basics.

The second thing to do is to make sure to search Arqade to see if anyone has already asked your question. If you still don't know the answer, then ask the question.

---

## How to ask your question

A good [minecraft-commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-commands) question includes:

1. **A descriptive title**
   e.g. *"How do I disable fire using commands?"* instead of *"Minecraft command problem"*
2. **A sentence or two explaining the context of your question**
   e.g. Are you creating a data pack, an adventure map, a command block creation...? Letting us know why you're attempting something makes it easier for us to suggest alternatives.

   Another good habit is to mention the platform and version number in your question, e.g., Java Minecraft 1.14.3 or Bedrock Minecraft 1.12.
3. **What your problem is or where you're stuck**
   Show where you're up to, including commands that may be broken and/or specific things that an answer must accomplish to be useful to you.
4. **What you've tried so far**
   Including, but not limited to: commands, function files, data pack folder structure, command block settings, error messages, screenshots and really anything that can help us understand your question better.

---

## FAQ

Please add to this list if you know of questions that are asked frequently.

**Java Edition:**

- [What are the basics of commands in Minecraft Java Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/354614)
- [How to color item names?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/353754)
- [How to use `/data modify`?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/351488)
- [Where to find vanilla loot tables](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/352296)
- [How to fix 'unbalanced brackets' errors in NBT](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/265668)
- [How to fix 'Invalid JSON' errors](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/304990)
- [How to test for a player at specific coordinates?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/198385)

**Bedrock Edition:**

- [NBT in Minecraft pocket edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334102) (everything in `{}` curly brackets)
- [How to fix 'Invalid JSON' errors](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/304990)

Comment: Pocket Edition has been merged into Bedrock Edition, right?

Comment: @L.F. Yes, Pocket Edition and Bedrock edition are now the same game.

Comment: [Relevant](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: Note that it is not at all needed to specify a version for MCPE, because since you can only use one version everyone is using one version