# Should we add a tag warning to [minecraft-commands]?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-warning-request

I often see [minecraft-commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-commands)-tagged questions where the OP doesn't specify which Minecraft edition they are playing. These questions almost always end up being closed as "needs details or clarity." To prevent this, we could add a tag warning to the [minecraft-commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-commands) tag, reminding the OP to specify the relevant Minecraft edition in their question.

##### Should we add a tag warning to the [minecraft-commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-commands) tag?

Note: This suggestion was originally made in a 2021 meta post: [Tag Warnings: Looking for suggestions of tags that often got low quality questions and would benefit a warning when trying to add that tag](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16001/4797). That meta post has since been closed since an SE Community Manager commented in that post that "These suggested tag warnings should each have their own dedicated discussion, rather than simply having them all as answers here."

Quoting [Ability to block/warn about certain combinations of tags](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15699/4797):

> We already have [blocked
> tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295148/805262) and tag
> warnings, but we need to expand this feature to block or warn about
> certain *combinations* of tags, not just the presence/absence of a
> certain tag.
>
> This argument stems off of the problem where multiple tags are
> necessary, like with [minecraft-commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-commands). We could have something
> like:
>
> [image: Minecraft Servers Tag Block]
>
> This example was from [this
> argument](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15698/250180).
>
> Here, the tag would be blocked *until* you add one of the other tags
> that are required with it. We could have a combination block on
> [minecraft-commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-commands) unless the question also has
> [minecraft-java-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition) or [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition). This
> will catch people making the common mistake before it happens, saving
> them from having to wait long periods of time as their question is
> closed and reopened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I set up the warning. It'll look like this when triggered:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

**Yes**, [minecraft-commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-commands) should have a tag warning reminding the OP to specify the relevant Minecraft edition in their question and provide other necessary details to prevent it from being closed as "needs details or clarity." The tag warning could be something like this (based on the tag wiki; feel free to suggest improvements):

> The **[minecraft-commands] tag must be used with a relevant Minecraft edition tag**. Please specify which edition you are playing and add one of the following tags: [minecraft-java-edition], [minecraft-bedrock-edition], or [minecraft-education-edition]. **Include details about the issue you're having and what you've tried so far to solve it.** For more information, please consult our [guide on how to ask a Minecraft commands question](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13507).

Comment: Consider adding a link to [What to do before asking a minecraft-commands question?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13507/what-to-do-before-asking-a-minecraft-commands-question)

Comment: @pppery Alright, I've added the link.

Comment: Rather than "not allowed without", I think it would be better as *"The [minecraft-commands] tag must be used with a relevant Minecraft edition tag."*. Removing a double-negative.

Comment: @Robotnik Good idea. I've edited the tag warning text.